# Output result of cli command to a file using awk to get columns

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I want to record the RSSI at a certain point with the distance that point is from a router. The distance will be user input and so will the output file name so the user will type something like:

```
sh rssi.sh output.csv 20
```

where output.csv is the csv I want to append the results to and 20 is the distance

at the moment rssi.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSSI_CSV=$1
DISTANCE=$2
RSSI=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}\')

awk '{print $DISTANCE, $RSSI}' > $RSSI_CSV
```

This creates RSSI_CSV as per user input but doesn't print the required values in it and I'm not sure why.

I imagine it's

```
awk '{print $DISTANCE, $RSSI}' > $RSSI_CSV
```

that isn't working as echo RSSI or echo DISTANCE both output the values to the screen. I'm using awk as I want to have columns so i can output a csv file, perhaps though there is a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "append the results"? Do you want a comma (or some opther) separator?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your `awk` need to pass the variables using the `-v` option and use the `BEGIN` block as no input is given. Also note that a single `>` will **not** append but overwrite the file. For appending you need `>>`:

```
awk -vD=$DISTANCE -vR=$RSSI 'BEGIN{print D,R}' >> $RSSI_CSV
```

Demo:

```
$ DISTANCE=20

$ RSSI=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}')

$ awk -vD=$DISTANCE -vR=$RSSI 'BEGIN{print D,R}' 
20 -47
```

Note: I believe you want comma separated values so:

```
$ awk -vD=$DISTANCE -vR=$RSSI 'BEGIN{print D","R}' 
20,-47
```

However `awk` is overkill for printing variables just use good old `echo`:

```
$ echo "$DISTANCE,$RSSI"
20,-47
```

Comment: It's hard to say what mistake you have made without posting your code but this is tested and works http://ideone.com/cd21JU I have pointed out the `awk` mistakes but the right solution is too use `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `awk` to print two shell variables.

```
printf "%s,%s\n" "$DISTANCE" "$RSSI" >> "$RSSI_CSV"
```

Comment: Will I need to do '>> $RSSI_CSV' to append the result?

Comment: Yes, ">" alone would overwrite the file. The benefit of using `printf` here is that it is a shell built-in, so it doesn't have to spawn a new process just to add to the file. I'll update the answer to handle appends better.

Comment: You should really use `printf "%s,%s\n" "$DISTANCE" "$RSSI" >> "$RSSI_CSV" to handle edge cases with no nasty surprises.

Comment: `printf` is not necessarily any more of a shell builtin than is `echo`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Could you provide an example where using "%s" produces a different result than direct interpolation? @WilliamPursell No, `echo` would work just as well. I just meant to contrast `printf` with `awk`.

Comment: @chepner - for one example, try it with DISTANCE="100%".